# sending two request to server in yii ajaxly form submit

Tags: ajax, yii

I have a form with a dropDownList. I  will when dropdown has been changed, application send a request as **get** method to an action.

my js function is:

```
$('#SiteWidget_type').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
        url: "<?php echo CController::createUrl('siteWidget/au'); ?>" ,
        data: {id: $(this).val()},
        success:function(msg){
                    $('#W_1_layout').html(msg);
                  },
       error: function() { 
             //alert(error);
        },

      dataType:'html'
  });

});
```

But two request has been submit to action and i don't know why
[image: firebug screenshot]

Comment: Is `#SiteWidget_type` the id of the dropdown. Are you sure it is unique (only one element on the page has that id)?

Comment: @eskimo yes dude. It's unique.

Comment: Hmmmm... so weird. Maybe try put in a `preventDefault()` at the end of the success function? Doesn't really make sense but I'm just about all out of ideas

Comment: Also, if you put a `console.log("whatever");` at the beginning of the change function, is that registered only once?

Comment: Could #SiteWidget be getting changed once by you, then again by $('#W_1_layout').html(msg)?

Comment: Maybe event handler attached twice?...

Comment: @eskimo ReferenceError: event is not defined.

Comment: @mashingan no dude. i chacked it. I think problem is for Yii.